# How to interpret this correlation coefficient from rcorr of the package Hmisc

Tags: r, correlation

I'm searching for the relation between two variables. I did the command `rcorr` to find the correlation r using Pearson method. However, I couldn't interpret the results in the console. Any hint/help please? thanks

```
rcorr(ESS8all$stfeco2[ESS8all$cntry=="AT"], ESS8all$stfhlth2[ESS8all$cntry=="AT"],
      type="pearson")
```

[image]

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `rcorr`? Try `?rcorr`. Under Value it tells you what this output is. `rcorr returns a list with elements r, the matrix of correlations, n the matrix of number of observations used in analyzing each pair of variables, and P, the asymptotic P-values. ` If you need help interpreting, r, n, or P, that's not really a programming question suitable for stackoverflow.

Comment: Is this `rcorr` from package `Hmisc` ? That information needs to be in the question!

Answer (score 0):

The result says that the correlation between `stfeco2` and `stfhlth2` is 0.37 and that it is significantly different from zero, having been computed using 1981 pairs of values.